# Can I create a SharePoint subsite if one does not exist with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm attempting to create an application for SharePoint.

I would like this application to live as a subsite under the root site collection.

It would be great if I could give this to clients, and just have them deploy the WSP, have the package create a subsite, and then deploy all of my pages and webparts to this subsite.

I've been googling for some time, but can't seem to get an answer.

****ANSWER****

Instances of SPWeb have a .add() method that allows you to create a subsite.

I'm going to create a Feature whose sole purpose is to check for the existence of a "/whatever" subsite at the RootSite level, and if it does not exist create it during the FeatureActivated event.

I am then going to make my other features dependent on this feature to make sure this site exists before deploying to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a subsite = SPWeb... so just create one in the site collection programmatically by creating a new SPWeb in the featurereceiver of your solution? Or you can even script it using powershell...

Comment: This was SLIGHTLY vague, but it's been a day and I want someone to get the glory :)

I would just add for people reading this in the future, look at SPWeb instance's .add() method

Comment: in my defence, the question was slightly vague also ;) By the way, dont forget to turn ActivateOnDefault="TRUE" to save your clients the hassle of activating that specific feature...